# yii2 dektrium\user email

Tags: yii2

swiftamailer работает. как сделать отправку на мыло в dektrium\user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно настроить входные данные для mailer'a в секции конфига **modules** к модулю **user** конфиг для **mailer**:

```
...
'user' => [
    'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
    'mailer' => [
        'sender'                => 'no-reply@myhost.com', // or ['no-reply@myhost.com' => 'Sender name']
        'welcomeSubject'        => 'Welcome subject',
        'confirmationSubject'   => 'Confirmation subject',
        'reconfirmationSubject' => 'Email change subject',
        'recoverySubject'       => 'Recovery subject',
    ],
],
...
```

Плюс нужно сконфигурировать сам компонент **mailer** в секции конфига **components**

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => '...',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '...',
            'port' => '...',
            'encryption' => '...',
        ],
    ],
```

подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/mailer.md)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/70518)

Comment: Спасибо, принято:)